# Set select height cross browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, height, html-select

All, Coding CSS for Cross-browser is not an easy job. Especially for the IE browser, Frequently I found it is ok in other browsers like chrome and firefox. but not work in the IE.
Now I am stuck with it in blow code. please help to review it .thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/malaikuangren/Ed9KU/

```
<div>
<select size="2">
        <option value="0" >0</option>
        <option value="1" >1</option>
        <option value="2" >2</option>
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4" >4</option>
        <option value="5" >5</option>
        <option value="6" >6</option>
        <option value="7" >7</option>
        <option value="8" >8</option>
        <option value="9" >9</option>
        <option value="10" >10</option>
        <option value="11" >11</option>
        <option value="12" >12</option>
        <option value="13" >13</option>
        <option value="14" >14</option>
        <option value="15" >15</option>
        <option value="16" >16</option>
      </select>
</div>

div{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
select{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;   
}
```

Comment: What if you add `height: 100%;` to the `select` CSS?

Comment: @Joe.wang, uhmm, what was you question?

Comment: @AnaMaria My question is this code only work in the chrome or firefox. not in the IE. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**inherit the height of the parent div** to your select tag

like,

```
select{
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
     height: inherit;  // or use 100%
}
```

check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ed9KU/1/)

Answer (score 3):

It looks ok if you set the height of select element to `inherit` or `100%`